# Weka - StringtoVector Filter Not working

Tags: machine-learning, weka, nlp

I am practicing Weka using the Reuters data.  The StringtoVector Classifier works for converting my string data (shown below), so I can analyze the articles to understand what words predict the article type. If the article type is true, the original dataset said TRUE/FALSE, but I converted it to 0/1. However, it refuses to work for this one arff file using the StringtoVector filter on the "review" string.

I used the following StringtoVector filter while ONLY checking the review attribute:

```
weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R first-last -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -M 1 -tokenizer "weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\""
```

I get this error: 
**"Problem filtering instances: attribute names are not unique. Cause: sentiment" when only review is checked for the filter.**

Here is the header of my dataset/formatting for a few of the cases:

```
@relation text_files
@attribute review string
@attribute sentiment {0, 1}
@data   "cocoa the the cocoa the early the levels its the the this the ended the mln against at the that cocoa the to crop cocoa to crop around mln sales at mln the to this cocoa export the their cocoa prices to to per to offer sales at to dlrs per to to crop sales to at dlrs at dlrs at dlrs per sales at at at at to dlrs at at dlrs the currency sales at to dlrs dlrs dlrs the currency sales at at dlrs at at dlrs at at sales at mln against the crop mln against the the to to the cocoa commission reuter", 0"prices reserve the agriculture department reported the reserve price loan call price price wheat corn 1986 loan call price price reserves grain wheat per reuter", 0"grain crop their products to to wheat export the export wheat oil oil reuter", 0"inc the stock corp its dlrs oil to dlrs production its the company to its to profit to reuter", 0"products stock split products inc its stock split its common shares shareholders the company its to to shareholders at the the stock mln to mln reuter", 0
```

**Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?** I was thinking there might be a conflict with the fact the data might contain 0 and 1s as part of the words occurring naturally in the text.  I'm also thinking I might need an additional space before the quote for the string after the previous string.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the problem is the filter converts every term in a string into an attribute. Now there must be a term "review" or "sentiment" in your data section. Therefore the attributes are duplicated.

So, change the names of these two attributes like "myreview" and "mysentiment" or to something that is unlikely to occur in your data. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem because the word "domain" appeared in the data, causing the filter to misunderstand when recognizing it. My solution was to remove all the "domain" from the data and keep only the "domain" in @attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to avoid these attribute name clashes, is to use a prefix for the generated attributes.

The prefix can be supplied via the `-P` command-line option, the `attributeNamePrefix` option in the GenericObjectEditor or the `setAttributeNamePrefix` method from Java code.

See Javadoc of [StringToWordVector](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter.